# Storing user input data in a dynamic array of structures/ displaying said data. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, dynamic-arrays

So for my project I have to...

1. Create a structure using the format: struct PERSON{string name; int age; float gpa;};
2. Ask the user to enter the number of records they would like to enter.
3. Create a dynamic array p of PERSON type to be able to hold all records in part 2
4. Read data into array p in part 2
5. Display array p

However, whenever I run my program and begin to enter my data it won't let me enter more than one set of data and the output seems to make little sense.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct PERSON
{
  string name;
  int age;
  float gpa;
};
PERSON *p;

int main()
{
  int count;
  cout << "Please enter the number of records you wish to enter: ";
  cin >> count;

  p = new (nothrow) PERSON[count];

  if (p == nullptr)
    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter name, age, and gpa: ";

    getline(cin, p[i].name);
    cin >> p[i].age;
    cin >> p[i].gpa;

    cout << endl;
  }cout << endl;

  cout << "This is the content of array p: " << endl;
  cout << right << setw(8) << "NAME" << setw(7) << "AGE" << setw(7) << "GPA"  << endl;
  cout << "--------------------------" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    cout << p[i].name << " " << p[i].age << " " << p[i].gpa << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now, this format seemed to work just fine when I was copying data from a file into a dynamic array of structures, but I can't seem to get it to work now that I'm dealing with user input.

Here is what a trial run of the program produces:

```
Please enter the number of records you wish to enter: 3
Enter name, age, and gpa: Robert 21 2.1 // This is the info I tested

Enter name, age, and gpa:
Enter name, age, and gpa:

This is the content of array p:
    NAME    AGE    GPA
--------------------------
 -842150451 -4.31602e+008 //?
 -842150451 -4.31602e+008 //?
 -842150451 -4.31602e+008 //?
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've probably gone over the code two dozen times now and have been searching for an answer for quite a while. Any advice/analysis/comments would be greatly appreciated.

**So @AndyG suggested that I change the getline(cin, p[i].name) to cin >> p[i].name and that seemed to clear things up. Thank you!**

**Sorry to trouble everyone over such a silly muck-up.**

Comment: `new` doesn't return any kind of null if it fails to allocate. It throws an exception.

Comment: I have a feeling you need `cin.clear(); cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());` somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: Replace `getline(cin, p[i].name)` with `cin >> p[i].name` I see no need for a `getline` here

Comment: [Example without getline](http://ideone.com/cGTfF0)

Comment: @AndyG Thank you. That was seriously such a simple fix. Why didn't getline(cin, p[i].name) work though? I thought that was what we were supposed to use for strings.

Comment: @RyanKing: No, not necessarily. Only use `std::getline` if you want to grab an entire line. Very often, you'd use it to put a line into a string, and then put that string into a `std::stringstream`, and then use the stringstream to read/write from as if it were an i/o stream, which makes some i/o a little easier. `cin>> someString` will read from the start of a character until a whitespace character (newline, tab, or space). Your `getline` was actually grabbing *too much* data, including the `age` and `gpa` data

Comment: @Ryan King: I posted my comments as an answer, as it seems they did solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Problem

Your `getline(cin, p[i].name)` is actually grabbing all your input on the same line, and your later `cin` statements are going to be mismatched.

`std::getline` should be reserved for getting an entire line into a character buffer or `std::string`, i.e., it's not always the appropriate tool for reading in a string.

#### The Solution

Instead, you simply need to replace `getline(cin, p[i].name)` with `cin >> p[i].name`.

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/cGTfF0)

---

#### Other minor changes

Remove the `nullptr` check:

```
if (p == nullptr)
    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";
```

Because in C++ you will get an exception thrown if the `new` operator fails to allocate. Like [bku_drytt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29270359/27678) mentioned, you can wrap this in a try catch block instead, although I'd personally just remove it altogether.

```
#include <new>
// ...
Person* p = null;
try
{
   p = new Person[count];
} catch(std::bad_alloc& ex)
{
   cerr << "Unable to allocate memory for Person! Error msg: " << ex.what() << "\n";
   return 1;
}
```

Finally, don't forget to `delete[]` the memory you allocated for `p`:

```
   // ...
   delete[] p;
   return 0;
} //end of int main()
```

Even though your OS will most definitely clean that memory up for you, you should still ensure you clean it up manually. Good practice at least. Alternatively, you can use a `std::array` or a `std::vector` instead, which will still give you random access just like the c-style array of `PERSON` you already have.

Answer (score 0):

The **std::getline()** function is "misbehaving" in relation to your intentions because there is (I think) a new line character left in the stream input queue.

You can discard such characters by using the following command **cin.sync()**.

Why does this happen? Because **operator>>** does not read whitespaces, but **std::getline()** does, so when the **cin >> count;** statement is executed and you press enter, the new line character (from pressing enter) is left in the stream input queue, which is automatically read by **std::getline()** upon execution.

There are other functions that can accomplish this and perhaps someone more informed can tell us which is the best choice.

Here is a fixed version:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Person
{
    string name;
    int age;
    float gpa;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter the number of records you wish to enter: ";

    int count;
    cin >> count;


    Person* p = new Person[ count ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        cin.sync(); // added this to discard unused characters from input queue

        cout << "Enter name: ";
        getline( cin, p[ i ].name );

        cout << "Enter age: ";
        cin >> p[ i ].age;

        cout << "Enter gpa: ";
        cin >> p[ i ].gpa;

        cout << endl;
    }cout << endl;

    cout << "This is the content of array p: " << endl;
    cout << right << setw( 8 ) << "NAME" << setw( 7 ) << "AGE" << setw( 7 ) << "GPA" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        cout << p[ i ].name << " " << p[ i ].age << " " << p[ i ].gpa << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:
You do not need to check if Person* p is **nullptr** because the new operator will throw a std::bad_alloc exception if it fails to allocate enough memory. Consider wrapping that memory allocation in a try catch block if you really want to.

Comment: When I tried cin.sync() the program seemed to stop accepting anything after the first set of input information in the for loop. It wouldn't display anything after that either.